# Azure Pipeline Function App - deploy a single DLL rather than full app

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

is it possible to deploy a single DLL to an Azure function app using the Azure Pipeline? The reason being, I only want to deploy DLLs that have changed rather than deploying an entire function app. Thanks

Comment: I doubt it’s worth the hassle, what issue are you seeing that makes you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The current recommendation is anyway to use the Run from Package feature in Functions. This packages everything into one ZIP file and deploys this as a single unit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package

Read this issue on Github full description of the benefits: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The trick is to use for instance FTP to only publish the stuff that has been changed. The downside: you'll have to check the files to see what changed, and only upload those that have. And you might want/have to stop and start the Function App.

[FTP Upload Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops)

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to upload files to a remote machine using the File Transfer Protocol (FTP), or securely with FTPS.